# What is the correct way of storing custom classes in lists?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a simple class with 1 method:

```
setClass(Class="test_class",representation=representation(A="numeric"))
setGeneric (name= "some_method",def=function(object,B){standardGeneric("some_method")})
setMethod(f="some_method", signature="test_class",definition=function(object,B){
  object@A<-B
  return(object)
})
```

My objective is to store many of these classes in a list. I enter the following code to store 1 `test_class` and use its method.

```
empty_class<-new("test_class")
custom_list<-list(empty_class)
custom_list[1]<-some_method(custom_list[1],2)
```

Unfortunately, R gives me the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘some_method’ for signature ‘"list"’
```

What have I done wrong, and what should I be doing instead? I don't understand why `some_method` normally works, but fails when I put the class in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`custom_list[1]` is a list. You want the first element and need to use `custom_list[[1]]`. Study `help("[")`.